# Issue starting ROS launch-File using RQT Plugin push button

Tags: plugins, ros, qpushbutton, rqt

I implemented a RQT Plugin with several push buttons. The push button is supposed to start a ROS launch file. For some reason every time I start it I get the error message:  Shutdown request received.  Reason given for shutdown: [new node registered with same name]
Even though the launch file has only been started once. The launch file also works fine when it's started without the plugin.

This is my code sample for the implementation of the slot:

`

```
void PluginStartButtons::buttonPressedKameraStart(bool checked)
{
    QProcess* k_process = new QProcess;
    k_process->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
    QString command = "roslaunch neo_watch_launch thermal_rgb_camera.launch";
    k_process->start(command);
    system(qPrintable(command));


}
```

`

Do you have any idea why this error might occur?